# Seeing Entire Stack Trace in Android

Tags: android

I've been trying to debug my Android application and the bug has been fairly complicated so I need to know the exact stack trace.

I have been using:

```
Log.d("DebugTag", Log.getStackTraceString(e1));
```

but I noticed that within LogCat, the Text for the error message gets truncated. Hence, I can only see half the error statement even after saving the logs to a txt document.

Is there a more efficient work-flow for android developers to see the stack trace after an error has been detected?

Comment: Just try **e1.printStackTrace()** to get the complete stack trace. Also **e1.getMessage().toString()**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`public static void v(String msg) {
    android.util.Log.v(TAG, buildMessage(msg));
}

protected static String buildMessage(String msg) {
    StackTraceElement caller = new Throwable().fillInStackTrace().getStackTrace()[2];
    return new StringBuilder()
        .append(caller.getClassName())
        .append(".")
        .append(caller.getMethodName())
        .append("(): ")
        .append(msg).toString();
}`

I use this to log the message